CGContext Drawing Performance
When you are drawing simple shapes, I noticed there are two ways to go about it that basically provide the same end result:
First Method:
   override final func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100), cornerRadius: 4)
        context.addPath(rectanglePath.cgPath)
        context.setLineWidth(2.0)
        context.setStrokeColor(secondaryColor.cgColor)
        context.strokePath()

   }

Second Method
   override final func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100), cornerRadius: 4)
        rectanglePath.lineWidth = 2
        secondaryColor.setStroke()
        rectanglePath.stroke()

   }

I am curious to see is more efficient when you are doing heavy drawing with many more items.

The 2nd method has trivial more overhead since each convenience method has to internally call UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() and then call the matching context method. The 1st method avoid the extra calls. But the 2nd code is easier to read and write. Only worry about the difference if you actually have a performance issue. Then use Instruments to verify if the 2nd method is really slower enough to worry about.

Notably, the let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()! in the second example isn't necessary, since those methods do it internally.

True. Even without that line, does it still call UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ?

@Gizmodo What is "it" in your last comment?

I meant, does the second method still have to call UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), even without the let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()! line?

@Gizmodo No, it does not. Presumably the implementation of each convenience method will make its own call to get the context as needed, otherwise it wouldn't be able to modify that context. But since your code (in the 2nd method) has no need to directly access the context, there's no need for you to explicitly call UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext().
